# Duplicate Management on existing Duplicate Contact Records

Tags: administration, duplicate-management

I'm trying to implement Duplicate Management in my Org Salesforce. Everything seems clear but one thing really bothering me. While creating a new duplicate Rule, in the Actions section, "Action on edit", seems not working. I assume that "Action on edit" is the action that performs on existing duplicate records.

To be more precise, I have two existing contact records in salesforce. Ethan hunt and other is also Ethan hunt. I have duplicate rule based on email. And those two contact records does have same email. Now I have activated my duplicate rule. whenever I edit one of those duplicate records, shouldn't I be notified or blocked. But it not happening with me. Please advise me if I missing something. [image]

Comment: Are both the `duplicate` rule and `matching` rules active?

Comment: @JesseMilburn Yes.. I figured that if I edit email field in existing duplicate field then it's gonna pop out the error and existing records

Answer (score 0):

For users with Performance or Ultimate Edition, you can run [Duplicate Jobs in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_jobs.htm&type=5) to place records that are duplicates before activation of the Duplicate Rules into `DuplicateRecordSet`s

However, if you are like most customers on Enterprise or lesser editions, you need to do some work to coerce existing (i.e. last edited before the duplicate rules were activated):

**What doesn't work**

- You might think you could just "touch" using Data Loader legacy records by putting them through the Save process but not actually changing any fields. You hope that SFDC will run the records through the active Duplicate Rules/Matching Rules and auto-create the `DuplicateRecordSet` for you.
- Nope - this does not work

**What does work (but probably not useful in most cases)**

- Let's say you have a DuplicateRule/MatchingRule on `Contact.Email`
- If you used a script or Data Loader to change the emails from say `foo@gmail.com` to `foo@gmail.com.invalid` then the `DuplicateRecordSet` would be created. Of course, you would need to run the script again to change the values back from `foo@gmail.com.invalid` to `foo@gmail.com`. *Note that the toggling needs to be done in separate transactions.*
- Except in some circumstances, the above is dangerous as you'd need to disable automation and triggers and not have any automation via Change Data Capture or the Marketing Cloud Connector or who knows what.

*That is, Duplicate Rule logic executes only when the fields used in the Matching Rule(s) actually change on the save process.*

**What does work (but will be a pain)**

- You need to identify the duplicates yourself using SOQL, reports+export+excel, or apex scripts
- Then, create `DuplicateRecordSet` and `DuplicateRecordItem`s using most likely, Apex (but could also be done with Data Loader). Each `DuplicateRecordItem` is a junction record between the `DuplicateRecordSet` and the Sobject (`RecordId`) that is a duplicate